# Undefined method in controller (Routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new at rails and I'm currently working on an already existing application that handles butons like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_answer_path(ans) %>
```

That links to the file /answers/edit.html.erb but now I need to make a button that links to the file /answers/comment.html.erb how do I go about doing this?

I already tried with

```
<%= link_to 'Comment', comment_answer_path(ans) %>
```

but I get the error "Undefined method 'comment_answer_path'" even after adding this lines to answers_controller :

```
def comment
  ans = Answer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Did you add the route in the `config/routes.rb`?

Comment: you do not have that route defined. Add `get '/answers/:id/comment' => 'answers#comment', as: :comment_answer` to your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a route to your `config/routes.rb` and then restart the server. Something like

```
resources :answers do
  member do
    get 'comment'
  end
end
```

will create the `comment_answer_path` helper for you as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that solved the problem, can I delete those lines after restarting the server?

Comment: No keep those lines in, the server checks your `config/routes.rb` file when it starts up, so if you delete those lines, it will continue to work until you restart your server again and then you're at the same place you are now.

Comment: Thank you very much I think I understand routing a little bit more :)

Comment: @IvanH Make sure to give [the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) a read through, it explains a lot

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you've set up the routes in `routes.rb`.

You can use `rake routes` to see the list of all paths and their alias.

Comment: Thank you turns out I just had to add it to routes.rb, I got confused since there's no extra routes declared in the file, probably since the only ones that are currently used are the default new, edit, etc